# How do I write a bot (for 500px.com)

Tags: bots

I want to write a bot for 500px.com which automatically likes pictures and follows random people. Sadly I don't have a clue where to start, are there any good tutorials or something? I googled, but could't find anything useful really!

Comment: does anyone from 500px know that you're doing this?

Comment: You would start by learning how to program. Asking a question like *"How do I write a bot for X"* without even *trying* shows an absurd amount of laziness. Do you know how to program? Okay, great. What have you tried so far? Show us the code you're having an issue with.

Answer (score 7):

I work at 500px.  We'd really rather you didn't try to game the system, it hurts the community when you do and isn't fair to other users.

I mean, I'm a developer, I get that this might just be a curiosity thing for you.  Maybe you just want to see what you can do.  But maybe your efforts would be better spent, say, playing with [our REST API](https://github.com/500px/api-documentation).

But if it is that you're just trying to get more exposure, I hope that you'll reconsider your strategy.  Focus your efforts instead on contributing meaningful content, engaging with your fellow users, working on your craft.  When you game the system, you're advancing yourself on the backs of other photographers.  The more people that engage in this sort of behaviour, the harder it becomes to find meaningful content, and over time everyone suffers.

Comment: Well, I chose 500px, cause I rarely use it anymore and I'm just curious whats possible. I watched like 5-6 hours worth of youtube tutorials last night to get an idea how it works and already made some kind of auto-reply bot for reddit. But anyway, now that I have the possibility to talk to someone from 500px: I don't use it that much anymore because it's just soo slow and it's just not fun browsing through stuff on there,  even Flickr loads faster for me :-( Thought you should know this. (Actually love the design of 500px, especially after redesign, but it's to slow for me)

Comment: @devo good answer. However this has already hurt the community by now and I have seen some horrible pictures getting tremendous appreciation vs quality pictures getting none. It's a really sad state of promoting your stuff online. Same with Instagram and other places. No one cares about quality of what you put up, but about how many followers and the way it works is you follow to get followers. So me writing a bot is the same as me appreciating just for the heck of getting followers. So you guys should also think of a strategy to promote the right people :)

Comment: @deepankar-bajpeyi You hit the nail on the head there. I sometimes spend hours on capturing and post-processing an image (landscape) and get like 92 Pulse on average, while the guy next door takes a shot of their fruit bowl and peaks on 97+ Pulse. Come on. Why should I keep posting on 500px, tell me.

Comment: In case you are still working in 500px, 500px have TTTTTOOOONNNSSS of bots..... please fix it

Answer (score 1):

**No**

Your problem is concept -- you want to write a automatic function that acts as if it is a human entity. This means that even if this is desired by the company behind the http://www.500px.com website, this does come across as something impersonating a valid human user, and as such will need to face *and overcome* the usual challenges of such thing as filling in online forms, logins and verification methods automatically and reliably without being detected as a `'bot` .

This is potentially a very significant undertaking, and not to be underestimated. By posting this question on stack overflow you're pretty much giving away that you've very likely *not* got the basic skill-sets required for carrying out this task.

If this task is however in partnership or for the company behind the 500px.com website, then you will have access to very specific and first hand information about the details and website code and structure they use.

Both of the above conclusions - to me - imply that you're far below the very-probably required level of knowledge and you're going about finding that knowledge in entirely the wrong way.

Instead, find a programming language of your choice and learn it inside out and upside down, then you'll have (slightly) more chance at doing something like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! You're right, my skilllevel - when it comes to such things as I have requested here - is probably to low to build a "powerful" not detectable automatism, I just thought, it would be to hard to build something really simple, which is just browsing through stuff and faving a picture here and there. Well, if you know of any helpful sites for some very first steps in this direction, feel free to link them here, would love to read a bit about it! :)

Comment: before building a castle, you need to learn to build a small bridge...